# Can't tell exactly what does this class do, the responsibilities of it?

Tags: c#, refactoring, idisposable

So I Have this class:

```
public class GeneralService : IDisposable
{ 
    private readonly LoggingService _logginService;
    private readonly DataService _dataService;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public GeneralService(LoggingService loggingService, DataService dataService, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _logginService = loggingService;
        _dataService = dataService;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

        var eventBusProvider = serviceProvider.getService<eventBusProvider>();
        eventBusProvider.RegisterForNotification(this, EventTypes.Exception, HandleException);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        var eventBusProvider = _serviceProvider.GetService<eventBusProvider>();
        eventBusProvider.UnRegisterForNotification(this);
    }
    public void Execute(Action action)
    {
        LoggingService loggingService = _serviceProvider.GetService<loggingService>();

        StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
        watch.Start();
        loggingService.LogInformation("Start Executing");

        try 
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            loggingService.LogException(exception);
            return;
        }

        watch.stop();

        _dataService.CreateLog($"{nameof(GeneralService)} - {nameof(Execute)}: {watch.ElapsedMillieseconds}");
    
    }
    private void HandleException(Exception exception)
    {
        var loggingService = new LoggingService();
        _dataService.CreateLog(exception);

        loggingService.LogInformation("Ëxception was logged");
    }
}
```

And I have 2 problems, I can't describe the responsibilities of this class and I'm not sure exactly how can I refactor it according to industry best practices, any help would be great.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It _seems_, it serves two purposes: 1. Register to an EventBus to log Exceptions. 2. Execute some Action and log the time it took to do so to some service. First of all, you might want to split those two, because they seem to be independent on first glance.

Comment: Then you might want to consider using Microsoft Logging Abstractions. And quit resolving services here and use Ctor injection instead.

Comment: Maybe check https://codereview.stackexchange.com if this would be on-topic there. (I am not saying it isn't _here_ ... )